# Row reducing matrices in a field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory, finite-fields

I am looking at the 2x2 augmented matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
6&-3&3 \\
2&6&1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and have been told to solve the system in Fp. My question is that when I row reduce it, I find the answer to be (1/2,0). I am confused because I am not sure if 1/2 is an element of the field, and if it is not then what is the answer? That a solution doesn't exist? That a solution only exists if 1/2 is and element of Fp? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I think at some point, you must have divided by 3 and by 7, so $p=3$ and $p=7$ will also be special cases you will need to treat separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $1/2$ just means $2^{-1}$, i.e., the multiplicative inverse of $2$ in your field.

As long as $p\neq 2$ we have $2 \neq 0$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$, so $2$ does have  a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{F}_p$.  If you want to represent elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$ by numbers in $\{0, 1, \ldots, p-1\}$ then you'll need to figure our which element $x$ of $\{0, 1, \ldots, p-1\}$ satisfies $2x = 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

If $p=2$ then $2=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$, so $2^{-1}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: And in fact, if the field has characteristic 2, then the second row of the augmented matrix is equal to $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ which thus gives an inconsistent system.